# $scope not injected, still referenced. Why does it work?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, this

In the Angular Material Starter App, a 'UserController' is defined without injecting the $scope service.

So in the constructor function, variables are created as properties of the This object:

```
function UserController( userService, $mdSidenav, $mdBottomSheet, $timeout, $log ) 
{
    var self = this;

    self.selected     = null;
    self.users        = [ ];
    self.selectUser   = selectUser;
    self.toggleList   = toggleUsersList;
    self.makeContact  = makeContact;
```

But then, in the self.selectUser function, the value of the array self.users is referenced as $scope.users

```
  function selectUser ( user ) {
  self.selected = angular.isNumber(user) ? $scope.users[user] : user;
}
```

It works even though $scope was never injected. And if I change it to self.users, works as well.

Is $scope implicitly injected in every Angular controller? Does it automatically mirror the this object in a controller constructor function?

What's going on?

Here's the code https://github.com/angular/material-start

Comment: Do you have anywhere else in your code where you are setting $scope.users? Is the code ever hitting that if condition truthy block?

Comment: Have you tried running the app?

Comment: I doubt your code don't give a message like "ReferenceError: `$scope` is not defined"...

Comment: @joncondo I did not find any previous setting or injection. And the code works perfectly so I must be missing the injection.

Comment: @joncodo here's the code https://github.com/angular/material-start

Comment: @developer033 Here's the code. It's the Angular Material Starter App demo, not mine https://github.com/angular/material-start

Comment: As i told you it's not working. I updated my answer as well. the condition was never meeting say they could never see it but if you do little change or you just try to do console.log($scope) you see it's not working and you get run time error.

Comment: @jocondo Got it. The condition in 
self.selected = angular.isNumber(user) ? $scope.users[user] : user; 

never evaluates to true, because the argument passed to the function in the HTML ng-click directive is not a number, but an object.

so the value assigned is never the $scope.users (when I log it, i get the reference error) but the user object.

Comment: @JorawarSingh Thank you very much! I just did the same thing

Comment: Great! Glad that helped. I don't think angular will throw errors if the code is never executed as javascript is not a compiled language but an interpreted one. This means the code is only run for the sections that the program needs.

Comment: please mark as answered

Comment: so i was right from the beginning and still no thums up or accepted answer :-(

Comment: thanks now feels fare :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just cloned the repo and tested it's not working as you were saying .$scope is not defined error. You have to Inject to constructor to work it
No it is not automatically injected you need to pass $scope as argument to controller to use it otherwise you should get error $scope is undefined it can be like your giving conditions in selectedUser function and it never come to $scope in order to react on that.

```
    function UserController( userService, $mdSidenav, $mdBottomSheet, $timeout, $log , $scope) 
    {
}
function selectUser ( user ) {
      //try to change this line and run code and select a user you will get error
      self.selected = angular.isNumber(1) ? $scope.users[user] : user;
      console.log($scope) //$scope is undefine
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the whole code. It is impossible that without injecting scope can work. I think I followed your question.

Comment: I'm not the owner of the question. What I mean is that the asker is asking: *"why is the code working if I'm not injecting $scope anywhere?*"

Comment: Sorry I never saw the user name but it can't work he should get run time error as I got so many times 

Comment: @JorawarSingh I must be missing the injection somewhere

https://github.com/angular/material-start

Comment: Can you do console.log($scope) and see if it print out and what??

Answer (score 1):

The code works because the condition in

```
   function selectUser ( user ) {
  self.selected = angular.isNumber(user) ? $scope.users[user] : user;
}
```

never evaluates to true. The argument passed to selectUser in the HTML ng-click directive is not a number, but an object.

so the value assigned to self.selected is never the $scope.users (when I log it, I get the reference error) but the user object.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a defect in the code. This comment suggests the `userService` parameter was originally named `$scope`:

```
/**
   * Main Controller for the Angular Material Starter App
   * @param $scope
   * @param $mdSidenav
   * @param avatarsService
   * @constructor
   */
function UserController( userService, $mdSidenav, $mdBottomSheet, $timeout, $log ) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript is not a compiled language but an interpreted one. This means the code is only run for the sections that the program needs.**

See this sample code:

```
if(true){
   a = 12
}else{
   hkjkjdkjhkjsfdjhsdf87678
}
```

**NOTE**: This code will never throw any sort of error as the code is never hit.

In your example, this looks like an error in the code that is never hit. I'm not sure why you are not getting the reference error but it has to be injected.

This comment: https://github.com/angular/material-start/blob/master/app/src/users/UserController.js#L12

leads me to believe that it was there before but was removed in error.

However, the first commit on that file is missing the $scope parameter as well. Can you split out the if block and verify that the $scope is actually being called?

I have also looked through the whole repo and history on this. It looks like this is an error. A great chance for you to create a pull request and contribute to open source!